# invoking command while copying file over ps remote session fails

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a question regarding how to properly structure a command with powershell.

Here is the code where I am having the issue.

```
$python_command =
{
    param($script)
    C:\Python27\python.exe $script
    return $lastexitcode
}

$exit_code = Invoke-Command Copy-Item -Path C:\TestWare\jsonStuff.json -Destination 
C:\Tunnel\Tunneling\jsonStuff.json -ToSession $Session - ScriptBlock $python_command -ArgumentList $exec_script

#Clean up
ExitWithCode($exit_code)
```

I'm assuming there there is an issue with how `$exit_code` is formatted because when it has this value

`Copy-Item -Path C:\TestWare\jsonStuff.json -Destination C:\Tunnel\Tunneling\jsonStuff.json -ToSession $Session`

there are no issues. I want the python command to run as well though. Can these commands be separated or how would they work as one? At the moment, I am getting the following error

```
Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.
At C:\TestWare\run-test3.ps1:122 char:39
+ $exit_code = Invoke-Command Copy-Item -Path C:\TestWare\ ...
+                                       ~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Any ideas on how to fix? I am on Powershell version 5 as well.

(EDIT) Here is my ExitWithCode function

```
function ExitWithCode
{
    param
    (
        $exitcode
    )
    $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
    exit
}
```

Comment: I believe what you have is trying to call Invoke-Command with all of those parameters. If -Path is a parameter to Copy-Item, you need to make that clear. For example:

    Invoke-Command -scriptblock {Get-ChildItem}

will perform a directory listing.

Are you trying to get the result of the Copy-Item command? If so, you need to indicate to the Invoke-Command what the whole command is that you want to run, including it's parameters. It won't be able to tell where the Copy-Item parameters end and more Invoke-Command parameters start.

Comment: I do see what you are talking about and I believe that is what powershell is thinking that's what I am trying to do. I'm trying to hit knock out two things here and copy a file with Copy-Item from one computer to another and I'm also trying to run a python script on the other computer. I was hoping I could get this done in one line but I may not be able to. Is it possible to execute two Ps-Session calls here if these can't be separated?

Comment: Would passing the script that you want executed in -ScriptBlock work? 
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item <copy-item params here>} -ToSession <remaining invoke-command params here>

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. I just separated the commands and it works fine. I guess I'll see after some heavier testing if there is any issues with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) has many different parameter sets, but just two fundamental ways to specify what command to invoke [remotely]:

- via the `-FilePath` parameter, which expects a *local* script's path whose *content* is converted to a script block, which is then executed on the target machine.
- via the `-ScriptBlock` parameter, which accepts a script block (`{ ... }`)

Therefore, your attempt to pass a script block *and* a [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) call directly cannot work.

It looks like you need *2* statements:

- The `Copy-Item` call to copy something to session `$Session` with `-ToSession`.
- The `Invoke-Command` statement to execute script block `$python_command` in session `-Session $Session`.

You could only get away with a single `Invoke-Command` call if you read the *content* of `C:\TestWare\jsonStuff.json` into memory and passed it as an *argument* to the script block and acted on that argument accordingly.